# Recursive function fails in Java (ArrayList)

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, arraylist, subset

```
 static List<List<Integer>> finalSubset = new ArrayList<>();

 public static void main(String[] args) {
                ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
                Integer[] array = {1, 2 ,3};
                Collections.addAll(a, array);
                subsets(a, 0);
                System.out.println(finalSubset);
    
            }
static void subsets (ArrayList<Integer> arr, int pos) {
        if (arr.size() == 0) return;
        finalSubset.add(arr); //problem
        for (int i = pos; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            Integer temp = arr.get(i);
            arr.remove (i);
            subsets(arr, i);
            arr.add(i, temp);
        }
    }
```

I've tried out to make a code that prints out all possible subsets of given array using ArrayList and when I run it output is correct, but when I substitute `System.out.println(arr)` by `funalSubset.add(arr)` the output is:

`[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`

when it needs to be:

`[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], [2], [1, 3], [1], [1, 2], []`

what's the reason of such output?

Comment: `finalSubset.add(arr);` adds a reference to the `arr` ArrayList. You only ever create two arraylists (`finalSubset` and `a`) and add a lot of references to `a` to the `finalSubSet`. Instead you should `finalSubset.add(new ArrayList<>(arr));`, thereby making copies of `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same array list to `finalSubset` many times. You should create a copy every time you recurse, either when you add to `finalSubset`:

```
finalSubset.add(new ArrayList<>(arr));
```

OR when you do the recursive call:

```
subsets(new ArrayList<>(arr), i);
```

This way you have different lists that can have different things inside. If you only have one list, you just get the same thing repeated 8 times.

Also, you should add to `finalSubset` before you return, otherwise the empty list won't be added to `finalSubset`.

```
finalSubset.add(new ArrayList<>(arr));
if (arr.size() == 0) return;
```